# python/beautifulsoup - find multiple anchors inside class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a page structured like this:

```
<div class="multiple_links">
<a href="http://www.example.org/link1"> link1 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link2"> link2 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link3"> link3 </a>
</div>

<div class="multiple_links">
<a href="http://www.example.org/link4"> link4 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link5"> link5 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link6"> link6 </a>
</div>
```

I want to extract the 3rd link of every class. I've tried using this:

```
urls = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'multiple_links'})
for element in urls:
    url = element.find('a', href=True)
    print url['href']
>> http://www.example.org/link1
>> http://www.example.org/link4
```

But it finds only the first anchor of the class. I need as output:

```
>> http://www.example.org/link3
>> http://www.example.org/link6
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `urls = element.findAll('a', href=True)`
(like you used for find the classes)

urls will then contain 3 elements each time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have changed Input:

```
<div class="multiple_links">
<a href="http://www.example.org/link1"> link1 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link2"> link2 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link3"> link3 </a>
</div>
<div class="multiple_links">
<a href="http://www.example.org/link4"> link4 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link5"> link5 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link6"> link6 </a>
</div>
<div class="multiple_links">
<a href="http://www.example.org/link4"> link7 </a>
<a href="http://www.example.org/link5"> link5 </a>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
import lxml.html as PARSER
root_tag = PARSER.fromstring(s).xpath("//div[ @class='multiple_links']")
[[j.values()[0] for i,j in enumerate(r) if i==2][0] for r in root_tag if [j.values()[0] for i,j in enumerate(r) if i==2]]
```

output:
['http://www.example.org/link3', 'http://www.example.org/link6']

Here root_tag is list of div which having class 'multiple_links' that gets by using xpath.